# Chinese dictionary or list of ABB adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

I found a list of ABB colours, is there a list of ABB adjectives in general and their corresponding meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a list, but I can come up with a few:

| ZH | EN |
| --- | --- |
| 冷冰冰(的) | icy cold |
| 黑黢黢(的) | pitch-dark |
| 粘稠稠(的) | thick, sticky |
| 香喷喷(的) | delicious, fragrant |
| 亮晶晶(的) | glittering |
| 软绵绵(的) | soft, cushy |
| 孤零零(的) | all alone |
| 慢悠悠(的) | slow, sluggish |
| 绿油油(的) | kind of green |
| 急吼吼(的) | hasty, impatient |

Comment: thank you. I found an ABB list consisting of colours (of the rainbow!) here in stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide some other examples

响当当

静悄悄

胖乎乎

肉嘟嘟

湿淋淋

血淋淋

汗淋淋

明晃晃

嘎吱吱

羞答答

Comment: Would be better if you include translations